# How can I load website to Webrowser from cookieContainer HttpWebrequest

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control, httprequest, cookiecontainer

I try to login the website by Httprequest and is reponse some information. And I save the Cookie Response. So how can I know I login success, I try to load website with new Form by the Cookie but it's not login. So Could you help me...
This is my Code:

The code for Login:

```
HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://www.nike.com/profile/login?Content-Locale=en_US"));
            getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(myLoginCookies);
            getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            getRequest.UserAgent = userAgent;
            getRequest.Referer = "http://www.nike.com/";
            getRequest.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
            getRequest.KeepAlive = true;

            string postData = "login=" + username + "&rememberMe=false&password=" + password;

            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(getRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                    writer.Write(postData.ToString());
               HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();

               using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    returnData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                //MessageBox.Show(returnData);
               myLoginCookies.Add(getResponse.Cookies);
                if (myLoginCookies.Count > 1)
                {
                    return new NikeStore(myLoginCookies, returnData);                
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("login failed");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
```

And this code for Load website by Cookie return

```
public Form_OpenCart(CookieCollection oCookie, string url_page)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (Cookie cook in oCookie)
            {
                cookie.Add(cook);
            }
            url = url_page;
        }

        private void Form_OpenCart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            url = "http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/";
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                foreach (Cookie cook in cookie)
                {
                    cookie_string += cook.ToString() + ";";
                    InternetSetCookie(url, cook.Name, cook.Value);
                }

                webBrowser1.Navigate(url);               
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("huhuhu");
            }
```

Plz help me. I try so much, but I can't success.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced issues like that many many times when using HttpWebRequest for a HTTPS url. So i switched to Curl Lib c# . And it works every time.

Let me know i you need sample code. It is most likely missing cookies using HttpWebRequest some of them which are needed to carry on the session so try with CurlLib and use those.

Use this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0l2rkczij11m0t4/InfoSharing.rar?dl=0

Add all the Dlls to your Debug folder  , and in the project just refrence this `LibCurlNet.dll`
And use the class i sent. Simply use this to get html . Use post as empty if you want to use a `HttpWebRequest (Get).`

```
                    HTTP http = new HTTP();
                    http.setCookie("Cookies\\" + UserName + ".txt");
                    string Url = "";
                    string Post = "";
                    string r = "";

                    //Get info
                    Url = "https://www.example.com/reg/join?trk=hb_join";

                    r = http.Post(Url, Post, "","");
```

Comment: Could you give some Code Demo or some thing about CurlLib with dotnet...plz. I'm looking foward

Comment: @BuiHoang Give me 1 minute i will send you a class just add to your project and use it.

Comment: Yes.Anyway...Thank you so much.Sir